# How to dynamically add components

Tags: android

I have to display a grid of pictures taken from the database. Depending on the screen size of the user, I want to show more or less pictures.

1) How to change the number of pictures shown dynamically according to the number of pics from the database?

1a) Which layout would be adequate?

2) If there are more pictures than that can fit on a single screen, obviously it has to be scrolled. How do I define a page wise scrolling instead of scrolling little by little, meaning after each scrolling, next page will have all new members (just like we scroll Applications in Android)

At the moment, I have a TabHost layout for the main Activity and a LinearLayout for the grid type display activity.

I am using API version 10, so GridLayout is not available.

Any suggestions would be very helpful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I solved the problem by using a LinearLayout. I dynamically added views to it using:

   ```
   LinearLayout parentLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.parentLayout);
   TextView ChildView = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
   ChildView.setText("I am the child");
   parentLayout.addView(ChildView);
   ```

   I loop upto the available view as suggested by Sumit.
2. I had to enclose the whole activity's layout into a ScrollView and it made up for the invisible children in the dynamic layout

Answer (score 1):

`1) How to change the number of pictures shown dynamically according to the number of pics from the database?`

As far as this part is concerned use a for loop based on the number of pics available in your database, the only thing you need is to know the number of elements present in your database, which you then use as I have used `numberOfElements` here

```
 for(int i = 1; i <= numberOfElements ; i++) {

    LinearLayout lHor = new LinearLayout(this);
    lHor.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    //lHor.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(238,    233,    191));

    // Text View
    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setText("FAULT "+i);
    tv.setTextSize(20);
    // tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    tv.setTextColor(Color.rgb(255,255,255));
    tv.setPadding(12, 12, 12, 12);
    tv.setId(i);
    tv.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1.0f));
    lHor.addView(tv);       // Adding the TextView to the LinearLayout

    //CheckBox
    CheckBox cb = new CheckBox(this);
    cb.setId(i);
    cb.setTag("CheckBox");
    cb.setClickable(false);
    //  cb.setChecked(true);
    cb.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1.0f));
    cb.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    checkBoxes.add(cb);
    lHor.addView(cb);
    l.addView(lHor);

}
```

You might already know how to get the number of elements in your database, if not I used this

```
    // Method 3: Getting total number of entries present in the database
    public int getTotalNumberOfEntries() {
        String[] columns = new String[]{ KEY_ROWID, KEY_TYPE, KEY_DATE};

        Cursor c = myDataBase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
        int count = 0;

        for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {
                count++;
            }
        c.close();
        return count;
    }
```

========== EDIT ================

You can call this method in your onCreate() method of your activity

```
private void setDynamicContentViewOfThisPage() {

// Defining the Scroll View and the LinearLayout
ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(this);
LinearLayout l = new LinearLayout(this);
l.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
sv.addView(l);

// You will need to collect data from the previous Intent :-)

    TextView introduction = new TextView(this);
    introduction.setText("Set Text Here");
    introduction.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
    introduction.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    l.addView(introduction);


    Button instructionsButton = new Button(this);
    instructionsButton.setTag("Some Button");
    instructionsButton.setId(987654321);    // Random ID set to avoid conflicts :-D
    instructionsButton.setText("Click to read all the instructions");
    instructionsButton.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    instructionsButton.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    l.addView(instructionsButton);

    instructionsButton.setOnClickListener(this);


                     // Creates a line
                        TableLayout tl1 = new TableLayout(this);
                            View v1 = new View(this);
                            v1.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 1));
                            v1.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(51, 51, 51));
                            tl1.addView(v1);
                        l.addView(tl1);

                    // Version 2 (Creating Different Layouts)        
                            for(int i = 1; i <= 3 ; i++) {
                                // Creates a line
                                TableLayout tl2 = new TableLayout(this);
                                    View v2 = new View(this);
                                    v2.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 1));
                                    v2.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(51, 51, 51));
                                    tl2.addView(v2);
                                l.addView(tl2);

                                LinearLayout lHor = new LinearLayout(this);
                                lHor.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
                                //lHor.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(238,    233,    191));

                                    LinearLayout lVer1 = new LinearLayout(this);
                                    lVer1.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
                                    lVer1.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
                                    lVer1.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1.0f));

                                        // Text View
                                        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                                        tv.setText("TV "+i);
                                        tv.setTextSize(20);
//                                          tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                                        tv.setTextColor(Color.rgb(255,255,255));
                                        tv.setPadding(12, 12, 12, 12);
                                        tv.setId(i);
//                                          tv.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1.0f));
                                        lVer1.addView(tv);      // Adding the TextView to the LinearLayout

                                        //CheckBox
                                        CheckBox cb = new CheckBox(this);
                                        cb.setClickable(false);
//                                          cb.setChecked(true);
                                        cb.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1.0f));
                                        cb.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                                        lVer1.addView(cb);

                                 lHor.addView(lVer1);

                                    LinearLayout lVer = new LinearLayout(this);
                                    lVer.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
                                    lVer.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
                                    lVer.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1.0f));

                                        Button showsomeOtherButton = new Button(this);
                                        showsomeOtherButton.setTag("showSomeButton");
                                        showsomeOtherButton.setId(i);
                                        showsomeOtherButton.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1.0f));
                                        showsomeOtherButton.setText("View Image");
//                                          showsomeOtherButton.setEnabled(false);
                                        lVer.addView(showsomeOtherButton);

                                        Button someOtherDataButton = new Button(this);
                                        someOtherDataButton.setId(i);
                                        someOtherDataButton.setTag("someOtherButton");
                                        someOtherDataButton.setText("Do this action " + i);
//                                          someOtherDataButton.setEnabled(false);
                                        someOtherDataButton.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1.0f));
                                        lVer.addView(someOtherDataButton);

                                        showsomeOtherButton.setOnClickListener(this);
                                        someOtherDataButton.setOnClickListener(this);

                                lHor.addView(lVer);
                                l.addView(lHor);

                                // Creates a line
                                TableLayout tl3 = new TableLayout(this);
                                    View v3 = new View(this);
                                    v3.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 1));
                                    v3.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(51, 51, 51));
                                    tl3.addView(v3);
                                l.addView(tl3);

                               }

                            // Creates a line
                            TableLayout tl3 = new TableLayout(this);
                                View v3 = new View(this);
                                v3.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 1));
                                v3.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(51, 51, 51));
                                tl3.addView(v3);
                            l.addView(tl3);

        Button nextPageButton = new Button(this);
        nextPageButton.setTag("goToNExtPageButton");
        nextPageButton.setId(98765432);
        nextPageButton.setText("Go To Next Page");
        nextPageButton.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        //nextPageButton.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams=new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        layoutParams.gravity=Gravity.CENTER;
        nextPageButton.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

        l.addView(nextPageButton);

// Set the content View to this
    this.setContentView(sv);    
}
}
```

Comment: thanks for the snippet.
Which layout should I have? And how can I control where exactly in the screen the elements will be added?
I use a different logic to get the elements, anyways thanks.

Comment: I am new to this too, so I experiment with things, I am attaching the codes in my answer with which I experimented dynamic view, please explore and modify the code according to your needs, hope it helps :-)

.... Following the attached code you will understand how things are placed in the dynamic view ... controlling where exactly the elements lie on screen is completely based upon how you code it .... you have to place the elements in an order as you will do in xml layouts